# C# and JSON fields with weird characters in the name (like @)

Tags: c#, json

I use Json.Net as (de)serializer. So I try to send a request with JSON body like:

```
 {  "Person" : {  "@personName" : "Name",     "@personAge" : 26,   } }
```

And the same body should be received in response. But I use "personName" and "personAge" fields for serializing the values, but I need to add "@" at the beginning of their names. As you know C# uses "@" for one can use reserved words as a variable name, so there should be some trick how to do it. Unfortunately I couldn't anything about how to do this.

I hope somebody ran at such issue and has solution for it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: even if `personName` and `personAge` are variable names, when they are enclosed in quotes, C# will treat them as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Person
{
  [JsonProperty("@personName")]
  public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Use a JsonPropertyAttribute to specify the serialized property name.

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for. Unfortunately documentation that is inside archive is working incorrectly.
Anyway, I'll try this attribute, but I think it'll work fine :)